# Access value from custom.properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am working on a `Spring MVC` + `Thymeleaf` project. There is a `test.properties` file directly under `resources` folder, like -`resources/test.properties`.

i.e. `test.properties` file contains following key:value pairs that I want to access in the view.

```
sample.key=key
```

`property-placeholder` is in the `servlet-context.xml` file.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*.properties"/>
```

and `applicationContext.xml` holds -

```
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
          p:basenames="/WEB-INF/i18n/messages, /WEB-INF/i18n/application"
          p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>

    <bean id="messageSourceAccessor" class="org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageSource"/>
    </bean>
```

When I try to access `sample.key` in `test.html` file it shows

> `??sample.key_en_US??` rather showing the actual value.

```
<p th:text="#{recaptcha.site.key}"></p>
```

Most of the solutions I found on the internet is based on `Spring boot` and `Java based configuration`. Could not find any related to **xml based** config.

If it helps - I am using `spring version 4.0.5.RELEASE` and `thymeleaf version 2.1.3.RELEASE`.
*p.s. I am not an expert in `.xml` based configuration.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lots of trail and error and trying out a bunch of solutions I found two ways of doing it -

1. Rather using `p:basenames="... , ..."` if I use `<util:list>` to add `test.properties` file along with existing `.properties` files, solves the issue.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
    p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false">
    <property name="basenames">
        <util:list>
            <value>classpath:test</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/i18n/messages</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/i18n/application</value>
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

2. or use existing one and append `classpath:test`

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
          p:basenames="/WEB-INF/i18n/messages, /WEB-INF/i18n/application, classpath:test"
          p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>
```

`p:basename` directly looks up at `webapp` folder. `classpath:` was the key point here to locate `test.properties` file under `resources` folder.